# How to make a textX grammar recognize normal strings and special keywords

Tags: textx

I feel like I am missing something very simple. I am trying to create a textX grammar that would make my parser to recognize normal text tokens vs special keywords. In the following grammar, I cannot make textX to recognize my `[LINK ...]` keyword represented by the `SpecialKeyword` rule because it gets absorbed by the more general `NormalString` rule.

The input I am getting is as follows:

```
['\n', 'Text part before [LINK: REQ-001] Text part after.', '\n', 'Text part before [LINK: REQ-002] Text part after.', '\n']
```

While I would like it to be:

```
['\n', 'Text part before ', My Link object with 'REQ-001', 'Text part after.', '\n', 'Text part before ', My Link object with 'REQ-002', 'Text part after.', '\n']
```

A related question is: how can I make the `NormalString` rule to support multiline strings?

```
from textx import metamodel_from_str

mm = metamodel_from_str('''
Text:
    parts+=TextPart;

TextPart[noskipws]:
  (NormalString | SpecialKeyword | '\n')
;

NormalString[noskipws]:
  !SpecialKeyword /(.*)?/ // this is too greedy
;

SpecialKeyword[noskipws]:
  Link // more keywords are coming later
;

Link[noskipws]:
  '[LINK: ' value = /[^\\]]*/ ']'
;
''')


textx_input = '''
Text part before [LINK: REQ-001] Text part after.
Text part before [LINK: REQ-002] Text part after.
'''


model = mm.model_from_str(textx_input, debug=False)

print(model.parts)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. The solution is to match a single char after each negative assertion in `NormalString` and then repeat. Also, matching across multiple lines is achieved by `(?ms)` regex param.

More can be read in [the textX docs](http://textx.github.io/textX/stable/grammar/#matches).

`Link` rule is common which will result in Python object, so you need to extract actual keyword which should be a match rule resulting in a Python string.

Here is the full solution:

```py
from textx import metamodel_from_str

mm = metamodel_from_str('''
Text:
    parts+=TextPart;

TextPart[noskipws]:
  Link | NormalString
;

NormalString[noskipws]:
  (!SpecialKeyword /(?ms)./)*
;

SpecialKeyword:
  LinkKW // more keywords are coming later
;

LinkKW: '[LINK: ';

Link[noskipws]:
   LinkKW value = /[^\\]]*/ ']'
;
''')


textx_input = '''
Text part before [LINK: REQ-001] Text part after.
Text part before [LINK: REQ-002] Text part after.
'''


model = mm.model_from_str(textx_input, debug=True)

print(model.parts)
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. I can confirm that it splits the parts correctly now, and it works for multiline strings as well. I was trying all kinds of combinations of `*` and `*?` but couldn't think of switching to by-character match.